# ¿Como Alinear el contenido de un Placeholder dentro de un TextArea?

Tags: html, css

Bien mi problema es que tengo un `<textarea>` en mi pagina y utilizo el atributo `placeholder=` para darle el valor de *usuario* tal que :
`<textarea id="usuario_nick" placeholder="usuario">`

El problema es que el texto **dentro** del *textarea* se alinea automáticamente a la izquierda pero quiero que se alinee hacia el centro del *textarea* no me refiero solo horizontalmente también verticalmente justo en el centro es posible?
Existe una forma de mover solo el valor del placeholder en ese *textarea* como un `padding-top y right` ?.

Se que se puede tomar el `placeholder` con `::-webkit-input-placeholder` pero esto me toma todos y quiero que suceda solo en 1 especifico.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Se que se puede tomar el placeholder con ::-webkit-input-placeholder pero esto me toma todos y quiero que suceda solo en 1 especifico.

Solo debes **anteponer** el `selector` sobre el cual deseas modificar el `pseudo-elemento` [`::placeholder`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::placeholder). El `selector` puede ser una clase (`eg: .miclase`), un id (`eg: #miId`), etc.

> quiero que se alinee hacia el centro del textarea no me refiero solo horizontalmente también verticalmente justo en el centro es posible?

Para alinearlo verticalmente puedes indicar un `height` específico para el `textarea` y luego el mismo valor para el `line-height` del `placeholder`.

> Existe una forma de mover solo el valor del placeholder en ese textarea como un padding-top y right ?.

Si, solo debes indicar el `padding-top` que quieres aplicar.

Así por ejemplo:

```css
.ph-center {
  height: 100px;
}
.ph-center::-webkit-input-placeholder {
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 100px;/* Centrado vertical */
}
```

```html
<textarea placeholder="usuario"></textarea>
<textarea class="ph-center" placeholder="usuario"></textarea>
```

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta amigo @Marcos es una forma de hacerlo

Answer (score 5):

Puedes acceder mediante id.

Este sería el código:

```css
#miid::placeholder {
  color: red;
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 30px;
}
```

```html
<textarea id="miid" placeholder="placeholder" rows="5"></textarea>
```

Comment: Gracias @Carmen exactamente lo que necesitaba

Comment: No hay de que, me alegro que te sirva